# The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported exception (in Java program for migration)

Tags: java, sql, database, exception, migration

I have a program to migrate data from an oracle database to a SQL Server database with the same structure. 
    private void migrateAllDataToMssql() throws Exception {

```
    Connection connOracle = DBConnection.getConnection();
    Connection connMssql = DBConnection.getConnectionToMsSql();

    Statement selectAll = connOracle.createStatement();

    ResultSet tableResultSet = selectAll.executeQuery("select table_name from dba_tables where owner= 'USER1'");

            //insert to mssql db
     while(tableResultSet.next()) {
         String tableName = tableResultSet.getString("table_name");
         if(tableName.equals("DATABASECHANGELOG_CORE") || tableName.equals("GLOBAL_PARAM") || 
             tableName.equals("LOG") || tableName.equals("ORDERS") ||  tableName.equals("ORDER_BOOK")) {             
             System.out.println("do nothing");
         }
         else {
             System.out.println(tableName);
             try (PreparedStatement s1 = connOracle.prepareStatement("select * from " + tableName);
                     ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery()) {
                    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

                    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++)
                        columns.add(meta.getColumnName(i));

                     String identityInsertOn = "";
                     String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " ("
                              + columns.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                              + ") VALUES ("
                              + columns.stream().map(c -> "?").collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
                              + ")";
                     String identityInsertOff = "";

                     if(tableName.equals("COMMODITY") || tableName.equals("DELIVERY_CODE") ||
                     tableName.equals("DELIVERY_CODE_ENUM") || tableName.equals("INS_CLASS") || 
                         tableName.equals("ORDER_TYPE")  || tableName.equals("PRIVS_TO_ROLES") ||
                     tableName.equals("PROD_DEF_GROUP") || tableName.equals("RESULTS") || 
                         tableName.equals("ROLES")) {
                         identityInsertOn = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + tableName + " ON ";
                         identityInsertOff = " SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + tableName + " OFF ";
                     }
                    System.out.println(sql);

                    try (PreparedStatement s2 = connMssql.prepareStatement(
                           identityInsertOn +
                           sql +
                           identityInsertOff
                    )) {

                        while (rs.next()) {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                                System.out.println(meta.getColumnType(i) + " " + i); //log which data type the column has

                                    s2.setObject(i, rs.getObject(i));

                            }


                            s2.addBatch();
                        }

                        s2.executeBatch();
                    }
                }
     }}

    }
```

It actually works fine but at some tables there occurs this SQLServerException:

> Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DataTypes.throwConversionError(DataTypes.java:1094)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1595)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObjectNoType(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1493)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1502)
>       at test.DatabaseDataMigrator2.migrateAllDataToMssql(DatabaseDataMigrator2.java:179)
>       at test.DatabaseDataMigrator2.main(DatabaseDataMigrator2.java:36)

I have checked which data types the tables have and they have in common that there is a TIMESTAMP data type in each table of them but at some other tables where TIMESTAMP occurs as well, the exception does not appear. What could be the reason for this exception?

Comment: Don't you think you should use a tool for the migration, instead of programming it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I actually wanted to but this is a task which I got to develop myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to check if it was a timestamp column and if so then replace `setObject` with `setDate`

```
while (rs.next()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
         System.out.println("Column type: " + meta.getColumnType(i) + " Iteration: " + i); //log which data type the column has
         if(meta.getColumnType(i) == 93) {
              s2.setDate(i, rs.getDate(i));
        }else {
              s2.setObject(i, rs.getObject(i));
                                }                                   
                            }
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) columnType==93 means timestamp so that is what is checked in the if clause. After doing that the insert and set works fine.